# How to refer to a different directory to cmake while running cmake commands from a batch script on Windows

Tags: batch-file, cmake, windows-10, git-bash

I come from a Linux Unix background and I am trying to covert a very simple `.sh` to a `.bat` script.

I want to run a `cmake` command in a batch file on Windows 10. But I want to run the `cmake` command from inside of a build directory placed outside the source code directory. The source code directory is just along side the `build` folder.

```
::build_something.bat

mkdir build 
CD build

cmake ../SourceCodeDir
```

As you can see above that I want to generate all the build files inside the `build/` directory.

But the issue is `cmake` instead wrongly tries to find the `SourceCodeDir` directory inside `build/` complaining that `build/SourceCodeDir` does not exist. This indicates that I am doing the directory navigation wrong in the batch script. How should I modify the Unix based folder navigation to a Windows based folder navigation on the batch script?

Following is the **exact error** that cmake states:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/code/build/SourceCodeDir" does not exist.
```

**PS:**
I am *running the batch script from a git bash shell*.
I understand that the slashes in directory paths are Linux based but that should not be an issue since I am running it from git bash? Or is that one of the problems in the bat script?

Comment: It does not help even if I replace the path separators with backward slashes. Does Windows understand the notation `..\SourceCodeDir` means referring to a directory outside current? May be not and thats also a problem?

Comment: You should use the `-S` (source dir) and `-B` (build dir) options for the CMake configuration step. Build dirs are created if not exist. Your CMake call would then read `cmake -B build -S ../SourceCodeDir` And for the Windows platform the build step then could be run with `cmake --build build --target ALL_BUILD --config Release`.

Comment: "But the issue is `cmake` instead wrongly tries ..." - Do not *describe* the error message, instead show it **exactly**, as is. Would you correctly understand what CMake (or shell) tells you, then you could easily resolve your problem by yourself. And since you are asking, then something in this message is unclear for you.

Comment: I updated the question with the exact error that cmakes throws. The error clearly indicates that it is trying to look for `SourceCodeDir` inside the `build` folder.

Comment: @vre Thanks for the tip using `- S` option but using the - S option also suffers from the same problem that my question is about.

Comment: Please note that I am running this from a git bash shell on Windows

Comment: On the git bash shell doing an `ls -l ../SourceCodeDir` works but cmake does not pick the source directory using `../SourceCodeDir `. Very strange!

Comment: What's the content of your `CD` script? Can you print the working dir after its execution? Or is that simply a typo?

Comment: `CD` command in the script is to change directory to `build`